# Wordpress not using temporary folder

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to set up a Wordpress on a shared windows hosting.
I successfully installed Wordpress using the installer script, but I cannot upload any files. Neither the Image-Upload (I tried both variants) nor uploading a theme will work.

I added the `WP_TEMP_DIR` to the config, but it seems like Wordpress ignores the value.
I wrote a small script to verify I have write access to the folder.

```
<?php
include_once("wp-config.php");
$dir    = WP_TEMP_DIR;
file_put_contents ( $dir . "test" , "Hello" );
?>
```

A file is created successfully.

I also tried to set WP_DEBUG to true, but I don't get any additional information.

Then I added an error handler

```
function dump_error_to_file($errno, $errstr) {
  file_put_contents(WP_TEMP_DIR . 'php-errors', date('Y-m-d H:i:s - ') . $errstr, FILE_APPEND);
}
set_error_handler('dump_error_to_file');
```

Which saves all errors in a file in the given temporary folder. This works, but there are no errors related to file uploading, i.e. when I try to upload an image there will be no errors appended to this file.

Comment: Does this hosting have a way of viewing the server error log?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found one yet. I contacted support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the hosting companie's support replied that it is not possible to host wordpress with all functions (i.e. upload) on their windows hosting package and we had to switch to linux.

Answer (score 1):

for windows wordpress will need special permissions in order to update itself, install plugins and themes and access file writing functions http://www.customfitonline.com/news/2013/6/20/solve-wordpress-on-windows-server-problems/ folow this link for solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I wrote, I do have write permissions already set.

Answer (score 0):

When using Wordprss on Windows, Windows will sometimes interpret the *nix file permissions in unique ways. You may need to run chmod or the [Windows Equivalent](https://superuser.com/questions/106181/equivalent-of-chmod-to-change-file-permissions-in-windows) on your folders and set the [correct permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) within Windows.

If your shared host doesn't allow it, download Wordpress on your local machine, unzip it, and change the folder permissions either via Windows Explorer or if it balks, chmod. Then re-zip it, and upload to your shared host.

To fully test things, set up a local environment as a dev server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I wrote, I do have write permissions already set.
I cannot extract a zip file remotely. Also a zip file will not contain any file-permissions, as far as I know.